# i am trying to build docker image for wso2 api manager 4.2.0

Tags: dockerfile, wso2, wso2-api-manager, docker-entrypoint

hello guys i finished working on my wso2 api manager configs and now i am trying to build a docker images i followed docs and created zip file of wso2 folder and copied the entrypoint and docker file from github and run my script but i keep getting this problem

```
chown: cannot access '/home/wso2carbon/wso2am-4.2.0': No such file or directory
------
Dockerfile:107
--------------------
 106 |     # add the WSO2 product distribution to user's home directory
 107 | >>> RUN \
 108 | >>>     wget -O ${WSO2_SERVER}.zip "${WSO2_SERVER_DIST_URL}" \
 109 | >>>     && unzip -d ${USER_HOME} ${WSO2_SERVER}.zip \
 110 | >>>     && chown wso2carbon:wso2 -R ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME} \
 111 | >>>     && mkdir ${USER_HOME}/wso2-tmp \
 112 | >>>     && bash -c 'mkdir -p ${USER_HOME}/solr/{indexed-data,database}' \
 113 | >>>     && chown wso2carbon:wso2 -R ${USER_HOME}/solr \
 114 | >>>     && cp -r ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs ${USER_HOME}/wso2-tmp \
 115 | >>>     && cp -r ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/repository/deployment/server/executionplans ${USER_HOME}/wso2-tmp \
 116 | >>>     && rm -f ${WSO2_SERVER}.zip
```

i change the WSO2_SERVER_DIST_URL with its value:

```
ARG USER=wso2carbon
ARG USER_ID=802
ARG USER_GROUP=wso2
ARG USER_GROUP_ID=802
ARG USER_HOME=/home/${USER}
# build arguments for WSO2 product installation
ARG WSO2_SERVER_NAME=wso2am
ARG WSO2_SERVER_VERSION=4.2.0
ARG WSO2_SERVER_REPOSITORY=product-apim
ARG WSO2_SERVER=${WSO2_SERVER_NAME}-${WSO2_SERVER_VERSION}
ARG WSO2_SERVER_HOME=${USER_HOME}/${WSO2_SERVER}
ARG WSO2_SERVER_DIST_URL=https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/archive/refs/tags/v4.2.0.zip 
...
RUN \
    wget -O ${WSO2_SERVER}.zip "${WSO2_SERVER_DIST_URL}" \
    && unzip -d ${USER_HOME} ${WSO2_SERVER}.zip \
    && chown wso2carbon:wso2 -R ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME} \
    && mkdir ${USER_HOME}/wso2-tmp \
    && bash -c 'mkdir -p ${USER_HOME}/solr/{indexed-data,database}' \
    && chown wso2carbon:wso2 -R ${USER_HOME}/solr \
    && cp -r ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs ${USER_HOME}/wso2-tmp \
    && cp -r ${WSO2_SERVER_HOME}/repository/deployment/server/executionplans ${USER_HOME}/wso2-tmp \
    && rm -f ${WSO2_SERVER}.zip
```

and then run
`docker build -t wso2am:4.2.0 .`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that WSO2 AM does not provide binaries for versions `4.1.0` and `4.2.0`. Instead, it looks like you have to create them yourself for both versions.

**As of Feb. 2024**: WSO2 AM has pre-releases like `4.3.0-m2` which [provide binaries](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/releases) again.

So, if you change these arguments:

```
ARG WSO2_SERVER_VERSION=4.3.0-m2
ARG WSO2_SERVER_DIST_URL=https://github.com/wso2/${WSO2_SERVER_REPOSITORY}/releases/download/v${WSO2_SERVER_VERSION}/${WSO2_SERVER}.zip
```

(works with `4.0.0` and `4.3.0-m2`)

Difference between release with binaries:

[image: release with binaries]

and without binaries

[image: release without binaries]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/archive/refs/tags/v4.2.0.zip has the product pack. That url must be downloading the zipped version of the product code. You need to either build and get the pack (this is in `modules/distribution/product/target` location) or you need to get the product pack from the website. You can then host that product pack somewhere and use that url in the Dockerfile.